# Как сделать многострочный input с автопереносом строки

Tags: html, css

Я создаю поле для комментариев.

PS `word-wrap: break-word;` не сработало.

```
<h3>Комментарий</h3>
<input id="textComment" type="text" name="textComment"  value="{{ textComment }}  "
  style="padding-bottom:250px ;
  font-size:16px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;">
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте textarea вместо input

```html
<h3>Комментарий</h3>
<textarea id="textComment" name="textComment"
  style="padding-bottom:250px ;
  font-size:16px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;" ></textarea>
```